# What is asset catalog? I can't see any error

Tags: ios, png, app-store-connect

I read a lot of post, but I'm not able to solve. 
ios appstore icon are w/o alpha channel, but I still get the error: "Invalid App Store Icon. The App Store Icon in the asset catalog in '--name--.app' can't be transparent nor contain an alpha channel.
I'm sure I remove alpha channel from resources, but I still get the message,

After hate tried in every way to edit icon-1024.png, I ran (with ImageMagick)

```
find . -name "*.png" -exec convert "{}" -alpha off "{}" \;
```

at root of the project, so I'm quite sure; but error remain...
Edited:
**Sorry, I'm real dummy... I was working on old archive!**

Answer (score 0):

You should flatten it instead using

```
convert -flatten
```